# can i treat info.plist as an asset?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am re-grouping my project's folder, but I am not sure if I can treat `info.plist` as a `Xcode asset` and add it into my `assets` folder.. . so can I add it into my `assets` folder?

Comment: No, you should not do that.

Comment: Nope. The assets catalog is mainly for images and colors. The info.plist is a completely separate file that contains info about your project.

Comment: oh, thanks alot for letting me know about it.. I appreciate.. . ) and I am accepting the answer as correct for who ever posted a comment as an answer..  thanks.. .)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Info.plist is more of a project configuration file, which contains permissions etc. I'd suggest leave it at a root level of the main project folder, but if you still want to group it you can make a new group named "Config" or any name you want.